# How to specify callback function when filtering array with object elements in php?

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I have an array whose items are of a certain object type, let it be `my_object`.

The class defining the `my_object`s has a function that I want to use to filter the array. How can I specify that function when calling `array_filter`?

```
 class my_class{
     private $exclude;
     public filter_function(){
        return !$this->exclude;
     }
  }

 $array=array($my_object1, $my_object2, ....);

 $filtered=array_filter($array,'filter_function');//obviously does not work
```

`my_object1` , `my_object2` , ... are all instances of `my_class` and I want that the

```
$my_object1->filter_function()

$my_object2->filter_function()

,.....
```

be called for filtering the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to indicate the object as well as the method in your callback, using an array syntax as shown in the [php docs for callbacks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)

```
class my_class{
     private $exclude;
     public filter_function(){
        return !$this->exclude;
     }
  }

$array = array($my_object1, $my_object2, ....);

$classFilter = new my_class();
$filtered = array_filter($array,[$classFilter, 'filter_function']);
```

In this case, you need to create an instance first, then use that instantiated object as the first element in the callback, and the method name as the second element

**EDIT**

However, if you're trying to filter this collection of my_class objects based on whether individual objects have the exclude set, then you need to have a filter method for the collection:

```
class my_class{
     private $exclude;
     public filter_function(){
        return !$this->exclude;
     }
     public static filter_collection($value){
        return $value->filter_function();
     }
  }

$array = array($my_object1, $my_object2, ....);

$filtered = array_filter($array,['my_class', 'filter_collection']);
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, Then `$filtered=array_filter($array,[$array[0], 'filter_function']);`  should work?

Comment: No, because all that does is return the flag for an individual element (instance), and will then apply that rule to all the elements in the collection; it's not the callback function for the full collection.... see my edit

Answer (score 2):

If you want to filter the array based on return value of each individual object's `filter_function` method call, you could simply:

```
array_filter($array, function($obj) { return $obj->filter_function(); });
```

No need to clutter the original class with static methods as in Mark's answer.

Comment: Thanks but I get a PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in that line. maybe the version I am using does not support that kind of calling? I use php 5.2

Comment: Anonymous functions became available in 5.3. In earlier versions you'd need to define the entire inner function outside the call, and use its name in `array_filter` callback. Which wouldn't be very different from what Mark suggested (except for where the function is defined).